# Why do different environtments contain different command line options when calling man -ls? (environments: codecademy, cb.vu)

Tags: linux, bash, shell, command-line, ls

Why do different environments contain different command line options when calling man ls?

1. [codecademy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4zo4X.png)
2. [cb.vu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q3xtA.png)

Does it mean that I should just use **man** command with options before using the bash options for *each new environment* which I use?

Comment: From your screenshots it looks like maybe they have the same options, they are just in a different order on the man page?

Comment: Most likely because different versions of the `ls` command are installed. `gnu ls`, `busybox`, ...

Comment: @mjones.udri No, the list of options is full.

Comment: @user2467011 what?

Comment: @mjones.udri It's an answer to your question. The list length of options is different on the man page, but not only the order.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306)

Comment: @user2467011 oh, okay, I was just confused by your wording.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's nothing magical about `ls` - it's a program just like any other program. Specifically, one that' been around for a **long** time. as such, different environments may have slightly different versions or even different forks of it. It's usually safe to assume the common options (such as `-l`) would be available anywhere, but when in doubt - you should double check.